# Correlation matrix Table

Tags: r, output, correlation

I'm starting learning how to use r for my statistic analysis and I'd like to improve my report and have some nice looking table for my data. Right now I'm dealing with the correlation matrix output. I'd like it to be like the SPSS one but it seems I can't do it even though I found some code on internet. This one:

```
corstarsl <- function(x){ 
require(Hmisc) 
x <- as.matrix(mydata) 
R <- rcorr(x)$r 
p <- rcorr(x)$P 

mystars <- ifelse(p < .001, "***", ifelse(p < .01, "** ", ifelse(p < .05, "* ", " ")))

R <- format(round(cbind(rep(-1.11, ncol(x)), R), 2))[,-1] 

Rnew <- matrix(paste(R, mystars, sep=""), ncol=ncol(x)) 
diag(Rnew) <- paste(diag(R), " ", sep="") 
rownames(Rnew) <- colnames(x) 
colnames(Rnew) <- paste(colnames(x), "", sep="") 

Rnew <- as.matrix(Rnew)
Rnew[upper.tri(Rnew, diag = TRUE)] <- ""
Rnew <- as.data.frame(Rnew) 

Rnew <- cbind(Rnew[1:length(Rnew)-1])
return(Rnew) 
}

xtable(corstarsl(swiss[,1:13]))
```

But it doesn't give me back a table.
Can somebody help me? And also if somebody could give me some tip on how to improve the data report in general I'd be very grateful!
I hope I manage to explain myself a little since English is not my first lenguage. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `swiss[,1:13]` ? Do you have that many columns? Where do you get `xtable` from ?

Comment: In `x <- as.matrix(mydata)` where do you get `mydata` from? Try `x <- as.matrix(x)` as `x` is recognised as the input in your function.

Answer (score 1):

Not clear how you expect your output to look like, but this should help:

```
corstarsl <- function(d){ 
  require(Hmisc) 
  x <- as.matrix(d) 
  R <- rcorr(x)$r 
  p <- rcorr(x)$P 

  mystars <- ifelse(p < .001, "***", ifelse(p < .01, "** ", ifelse(p < .05, "* ", " ")))

  R <- format(round(cbind(rep(-1.11, ncol(x)), R), 2))[,-1] 

  Rnew <- matrix(paste(R, mystars, sep=""), ncol=ncol(x)) 
  diag(Rnew) <- paste(diag(R), " ", sep="") 
  rownames(Rnew) <- colnames(x) 
  colnames(Rnew) <- paste(colnames(x), "", sep="") 

  Rnew <- as.matrix(Rnew)
  Rnew[upper.tri(Rnew, diag = TRUE)] <- ""
  Rnew <- as.data.frame(Rnew) 

  Rnew <- cbind(Rnew[1:length(Rnew)-1])
  return(Rnew) 
}

corstarsl(swiss)

#                 Fertility Agriculture Examination Education Catholic
# Fertility                                                            
# Agriculture        0.35*                                            
# Examination       -0.65***    -0.69***                               
# Education         -0.66***    -0.64***     0.70***                   
# Catholic           0.46**      0.40**     -0.57***  -0.15          
# Infant.Mortality   0.42**     -0.06       -0.11     -0.10     0.18
```

An alternative way to get more information quicker is this:

```
library(PerformanceAnalytics)

chart.Correlation(swiss)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked! I have just one small issue, when I try to use xtable() this is what i get:
 % latex table generated in R 3.6.0 by xtable 1.8-4 package
% Fri Jul 05 14:00:19 2019
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rllllllllllll}
  \hline
And then all my data, it seems like xtable() doesn't work.

Comment: `xtable` will give you a Latex format. You can try something like `print(xtable(...), type="html")` to get the output as an html table.

Comment: My problem is that i get the latex code as output:
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rllllllllllll}
  \hline
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

And not the table itself. I guess I've to do something with this code to see the table in latex format but I've no idea what. If somebody could help me I'll be very grateful

Comment: It is latex code so you have to use Latex to view the table. This should help: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/137334/how-can-i-use-a-table-generated-by-latex-in-rxtable